# An AAC audio stream is playable in VLC for Android, but not in Exoplayer

Tags: android, vlc, exoplayer

I have an RTMP stream I want to play in my app using the Exoplayer library. My setup for that is as follows:

```
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
RtmpDataSourceFactory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter);
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
factory = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(rtmpDataSourceFactory);
factory.setExtractorsFactory(extractorsFactory);
createSource();

mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mActivity, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl(
        new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE),
        1000,  // min buffer
        3000, // max buffer
        1000, // playback
        2000,   //playback after rebuffer
        DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_TARGET_BUFFER_BYTES,
        true
));
vwExoPlayer.setPlayer(mPlayer);
mPlayer.addListener(mVideoStreamHandler);
mPlayer.addVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
        Log.d("hasil", "onVideoSizeChanged: w:" + width + ", h:" + height);
        String res = width + "x" + height;
        resolution.setText(res);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame() {
    }
});
```

Where `createSource()` is as follows:

```
private void createSource() {
    mMediaSource180 = factory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(API.GAME_VIDEO_STREAM_URL_180));
    mMediaSource360 = factory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(API.GAME_VIDEO_STREAM_URL_360));
    mMediaSource720 = factory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(API.GAME_VIDEO_STREAM_URL_720));
    mMediaSourceAudio = factory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(API.GAME_AUDIO_STREAM_URL));
}
```

My current problem is that only the first three `ExtractorMediaSource`s work fine in `Exoplayer`. The `mMediaSourceAudio` refuses to play in `Exoplayer`, but works just fine in the VLC Media Player for Android.

Right now I have a suspicion that the format is AAC-LTP, or whatever AAC variant that requires a codec available in VLC but not in default Android. However, I do not have access to the encoding process so I don't know for sure.

If this isn't the case, what is it?

EDIT:

I've been debugging the `BandwidthMeter` and added a `MediaSourceEventListener`. When I use the normal Video sources, `onDownstreamFormatChanged()` gets called, but not when I use that Audio Stream source.

In addition, the `BandwidthMeter` works fine, with bytes always downloaded in all parts of the stream and more bytes when the video stream comes in, but only in the Audio only stream that, when I call `mPlayer.getBufferedPosition()`, the returned value is always 0. Also, when I use the Audio Stream source, no OMX code was called - no decoders were set up.

Am I seeing a malformed audio stream, or do I need to change my Exoplayer's settings?

EDIT 2:

Further debugging reveals that, in all the Video streams and Audio stream, the same `FlvExtractor` is used. Even though the Video streams have the `avc` video track encoding and `mp4a-latm` audio track encoding. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because the stream was recognized to have two tracks/`sampleQueue`s. One Audio track, and one track with null format. That null track was supposed to be the video track, which was supposed to exist according to the stream's `flvHeader` flag.

For now, I get around this by creating a custom `MediaSource` using a custom `MediaPeriod`. Said custom `MediaPeriod` having code to separate the video and audio tracks of the `SampleQueue`s, then using the audio-only `SampleQueue[]` instead of the source `SampleQueue[]` when I want to play the audio-only stream.

Though this gives me another point of concern: There's something one can do to alter the 'has audio track (`flag & 0x04`) and video track (`flag & 0x01`)' flag in the rtmp stream, right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I'm new to ExoPlayer. But your comments helped me in debugging and getting multiple workarounds to the issue.

I tried to use custom MediaSource and custom MediaPeriod to address this audio issue. I have observed video format data coming after audio data incase of video+audio wowza stream, so the function maybeFinishPrepare() will wait for getting both video and audio format tag data before invoking onPrepared, incase if video tagData is received first. Incase of audio data received first, it wont wait and will call onPrepare().

With the above changes, I was able to play audio alone and video_audio wowza streams, where rtmp tagHeader with tagTypes were coming in the order of video tagData and then followed by audio data.

I wasn't able to use the same patch with srs server to play both audio_only and video_audio streams with the same changes. srs server is giving tagData in the order of audio and then video tagData,

So, I debugged further in FlvExtractor. In readFlvHeader, I have overriden the hasAudio and hasVideo variables. These variables will be set based on the first few tagHeaders(5 or 6). I used peekFully on input for 6 times in a loop. In each loop after fetching tagType and tagDataSize, tagDataSize is used to input.advancePeekPosition(), and tagType is used to identify whether we have audio/video format data in tagData. After peeking for first 6 consecutive tagHeaders, I was able to get actual values of hasAudio and hasVideo, and ignored the flvHeaders.flags, which were used to set these variables.

Custom FlvExtractor workaround, looked cleaner than custom MediaSource/MediaPeriod, as we will create those many tracks as necessary, as we are setting proper hasVideo/hasAudio values.